# Decrease polyline in google map when the marker moves towards destination(Android)

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-polyline

Please provide some idea,

I am trying to decrease the polyline in google map as the marker moves towards the destination.

I am hitting the google api for getting the poly line list frequently and redrawing the root.

I am searching for any best options...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under you onChangeLocation.

after requesting for new location. clear the map then create a polyline from your current location to your destination.
everytime you request for new location and you move towards your destination the polyline become shorter and shorter.

Comment: Tat's wat i am doing, provided when i move against my destination or take a new root, this system fails(I have to re-hit google API for Polyline, if i am in a new root).

And some times my current location is not in the road... its some where in the next street...

Comment: getting location using listener  have 2 provider the more accurate one is GPS provide but the down side of that provider is the too cloudy or you are inside the building. because it hard to get sattelite/s. the other one is the network provider. less accurate it point you to your approximate location.